# ASP.NET Core: Razor: Post QueryString as is to a razor handler

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a razor handler named OnPostDisplay that takes in a few [FromQuery] parameters and a [FromBody] parameter. How do I form the URL in my ajax request to this handler?
What I'm trying to achieve is extract query parameters from the window URL and pass them to the razor handler.

My code:
Code-behind:

```
public class MyNamespaceModel : PageModel {
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDisplay([FromQuery] string param1, [FromQuery] string param2, [FromQuery], [FromBody] ClientData ClientRequestData)
    {            
        //do something with param1 and param2 and ClientRequestData.param3

        return Page();
    }
    }
public class ClientRequestData { public string param3 {get;set;}}


I'm calling the page at:

http://localhost:12345/MyNamespace?param1=Hello&param2=World
and posting { "param3" = "carpe diem"; }

AJAX Post:

    var input_json = {};        
    input_json['param3'] = "carpe diem";
    let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var _url = null;

    if ((searchParams.has('param1')) && (searchParams.has('param2')) {
        //_url = '?handler=Display/' + searchParams.get('param1') + '/' + searchParams.get('param2') ;
        _url = '?handler=Display?' + searchParams;
    }
    console.log(_url); //? how do I pass both [FromQuery] and [FromBody] to the razor handler?
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',            
        url: _url,            
        data: JSON.stringify(input_json),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response));
            console.log(obj);
            
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the query parameter param1 and param2 now you have to include that in url. Send the `ClientRequestData` JSON object in the body of the POST request.

```
var input_json = { param3: "carpe diem" };
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

var _url = '/MyNamespace?handler=Display&' + searchParams.toString();

console.log(_url); 

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: _url,
    data: JSON.stringify(input_json),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        // Include the anti-forgery token if required
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response); 
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
    }
});
```